# Javascript Regular Expressions problem

Tags: javascript, regex

maybe I'm just misunderstanding Javascript's regular expression functionality but here goes...  I have an array with expressions I want to remove, and I go about it this way:

```
var removeThese = ['inc\\.','inc','ltd\\.','ltd','\\(c\\)'];

for(var i=0; i < removeThese.length; i++) {
  var find = removeThese[i];
  regex = new RegExp('\\b'+find+'\\b','gi');
  titletext = titletext.replace(regex,'');
}
```

So, in the above I expect any island (full word) expressions of *inc.,inc,ltd.,ltd* or *(c)* to be matched. My console on console.log(regex):

```
/\binc.\b/gi
/\binc\b/gi
/\bltd\.\b/gi
/\bltd\b/gi
/\b\(c\)\b/gi
```

Looks pretty good right?  But it's completely missing any occurances of (c) and when it replaces inc. it leaves the '.', so

```
This is a title (c) inc.
```

Becomes

```
This is a title (c) .
```

What am I missing here?

note, I would use a reg exp like '(inc\.)|(inc)|(ltd\.)...' but I have some items in that array that need special conversion (like 169 is converted to the © symbol before being searched for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(` and `)` are not considered word characters, so there is no word boundary between whitespace and a `(`. That means that your `\b` won't match there.

You could change it to something like:

```
regex = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)'+find+'(?=\\s+|$)','gi');
```

Which will remove the word if it is either at the start of the string, or is preceded by some spaces, and at the end of the string, or followed by some spaces. It will also remove the spaces before the string so `word (c) word2` will become `word_word2` instead of `word__word2` (Spaces marked by underscores for clarity).

Comment: @waitinforatrain. It wasn't before because I forgot to escape the `\`s. I changed it a bit ago to be `\\s`, so now it works.

Comment: Rocked it, thanks :)  One of these days I'm going to learn what these regular expressions actually do instead of cobbling them together.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this all with one regex.  I find regular expressions a lot easier to declare inside the `/match here/` syntax because you don't have to double escape things.  Anyway, here's the entire thing in one line of code and one regex:

```
titletext = titletext.replace(/(^|\s+)(inc\.|inc|ltd\.|ltd|\(c\))(?=\s+|$)/gi,'');
```

You can see a little test app here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wVDBr/.